# Is there any European country that requires or required its citizens to have completed the compulsory school as a driving license precondition?

Tags: romania

One of the many recent Romanian governments tried [to introduce a restriction for getting the driving license](https://www.romania-insider.com/romanians-finish-compulsory-education-to-get-driver-licenses):

> Romanians will no longer be allowed to get driver licenses unless they
>   finish **compulsory education first**, according to a draft Government
>   decision.

As far as I know that is 10 grades/ years.

I am trying to find out if any European country has such a precondition, as it sounds rather restrictive. [For EU](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/get-driving-licence/index_en.htm) the conditions seem to boil down to being a citizen, a minimum age, medical requirements and passing a test.

**Question:** Is there any European country that requires or required its citizens to have completed the compulsory school as a driving license precondition?

Comment: If the school is compulsory, doesn't that mean that anybody (of sufficient age) has completed it anyway? So all this does in practice is to slightly increase the minimum age for holding a drivers licence?

Comment: @quarague - "compulsory" _theoretically_ means that everyone will have at least 10 years of school, but especially in the country-side, this is not true. 10 years of school are normally finalized at ~16 years old, before the minimum required age (18 years).

Comment: @quarague There will always be edge-cases of people who didn't. People who didn't attend school in their childhood for medical reasons. People who didn't finish compulsory education due to mental disabilities (but I assume those wouldn't qualify for a drivers license anyway). Immigrants who didn't receive an education in their home-country which is recognized in Romania (I suspect that this might be the demographic targeted by this bill).

Comment: I hazard a guess that this enforces that drivers are able to read.

Comment: Your quote of EU conditions is misleading. You must be a **resident**, not a citizen.